# Simple Admin HelloWorld

Tags: admin

My config is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
        <module>
                <VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                </VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld>
        </module>
        <admin>
                <routers>
                        <adminhtml>
                                <args>
                                        <modules>
                                                <helloworld before="Mage_Adminhtml">VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld</helloworld>
                                        </modules>
                                </args>
                        </adminhtml>
                </routers>
        </admin>
</config>
```

I was hoping that would show something in mysite.com/admin/helloworld but it doesn't.

I have tried turning on debugging but i dont see anything showing up in /var/log/system.log

Shouldn't this do something even if my controller is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not enough to get an output. You need to have a controller that will handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, it may be very useful: http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world

Try this:

```
<config>
...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </admin>
...
</config>
```

and create a conrtoller in:
`app/code/local/My/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php`

Comment: That is for /helloworld/admin.../

Comment: My question is, should that alone even without defining a controller be enough to see *something* happen in either the system log or the browser itself?

Comment: Actually NO, you can't see anything without defining controller because you are overriding the admin router and you haven't define any controller.